# using webrowser, how to open multiple seperate windows?

Tags: python

I have tried using this multiple times

```
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("site here")
```

I i tried through an normal tab and an incognito tab

```
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito").open("site here")
```

But multiple tabs on the same window(or the 2 seperate windows) always open, help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your post to show the code you are using?